# Weird TypeError from json.dumps

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

In python 3.4.0, using `json.dumps()` throws me a TypeError in one case but works like a charm in other case (which I think is equivalent to the first one).

I have a dict where keys are strings and values are numbers and other dicts (i.e. something like `{'x': 1.234, 'y': -5.678, 'z': {'a': 4, 'b': 0, 'c': -6}}`).

This fails (the stacktrace is not from this particular code snippet but from my larger script which I won't paste here but it is essentialy the same):

```
>>> x = dict(foo()) # obtain the data and make a new dict of it to really be sure
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/data/gandalv/progs/pycharm-3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1733, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/mnt/data/gandalv/progs/pycharm-3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1226, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/mnt/data/gandalv/progs/pycharm-3.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_execfile.py", line 38, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) #execute the script
  File "/mnt/data/gandalv/School/PhD/Other work/Krachy/code/recalculate.py", line 54, in <module>
    ls[1] = json.dumps(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 192, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 250, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: 306 is not JSON serializable
```

The `306` is one of the values in one of ther inner dicts in `x`. It is not always the same number, sometimes it is a different number contained in the dict, apparently because of the unorderedness of a dict.

However, this works like a charm:

```
>>> x = foo() # obtain the data and make a new dict of it to really be sure
>>> import ast
>>> import json
>>> x2 = ast.literal_eval(repr(x))
>>> x == x2
True
>>> json.dumps(x2)
"{...}" # the json representation of dict as it should be
```

Could anyone, please, tell me why does this happen or what could be the cause? The most confusing part is that those two dicts (the original one and the one obtained through evaluation of the representation of the original one) are equal but the `dumps()` function behaves differently for each of them.

Comment: Are you sure it's an actual integer, and not some other object whose `repr` is `306`?

Comment: JSON is telling you the `306` value is *not a type it supports*. The fact that it has a representation that *looks* like an integer is clearly misleading here, because if it really was just an integer you would not have gotten this exception. Can you tell us what `type(the_306_value)` is?

Comment: @jonrsharpe @MartijnPieters It's `numpy.int64` so that seems to be the cause. My mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause was that the numbers inside the `dict` were not ordinary python `int`s but `numpy.in64`s which are apparently not supported by the json encoder.

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, numpy int64 data types are not serializable into json directly:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import json
>>> a=np.zeros(3, dtype=np.int64)
>>> a[0]=-9223372036854775808
>>> a[2]=9223372036854775807
>>> jstr=json.dumps(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 192, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 250, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/encoder.py", line 173, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: array([-9223372036854775808,                    0, 9223372036854775807]) is not JSON serializable
```

However, Python integers -- including longer integers -- can be serialized and deserialized:

```
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(2**123))==2**123
True
```

So with numpy, you can convert directly to Python data structures then serialize:

```
>>> jstr=json.dumps(a.tolist())
>>> b=np.array(json.loads(jstr))
>>> np.array_equal(a,b)
True
```